# how to set margins to imageview dynamically using display metrics in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hi am doing one application for all sizes. here i am displaying imageview  using display metrics if taken imageview in xml file my code is working for all sizes,but if i taken imageview dynamically that time while giving margins i am getting exception can u any one help me....

```
my code:

         ImageView I2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.caption);
                     captionbitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.practise));

          captiondrwable = new BitmapDrawable(captionbitmap); 
             I2.setBackgroundDrawable(captiondrwable);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutcap= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) I2.getLayoutParams();      
             layoutcap.height=(int)(50*(screenHeight/600));  
             layoutcap.width=(int)(80*(screenWidth/1024));
             layoutcap.topMargin=(int)(50*(screenHeight/600)); 
             layoutcap.leftMargin=(int)(15*(screenWidth/1024));
       // above   code working well for all sizes



            ImageView I2=new ImageView(this);

          captionbitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.practise));

          captiondrwable = new BitmapDrawable(captionbitmap); 
             I2.setBackgroundDrawable(captiondrwable);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutcap= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) I2.getLayoutParams();      
             layoutcap.height=(int)(50*(screenHeight/600));  
             layoutcap.width=(int)(80*(screenWidth/1024));
             layoutcap.topMargin=(int)(50*(screenHeight/600)); 
             layoutcap.leftMargin=(int)(15*(screenWidth/1024));


    // above imageview i gave dynamically that my code is not working so pls any one give me any        idea
```

Comment: can you show the XML where the first ImageView is defined ?

Comment: <ImageView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:id="@+id/caption" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   </ImageView> but my xml code is working fine.

Comment: i got problm in when i gave imageview dynamically that time